# pythonのリストとlog関数について

Tags: python, python3

float型のリストがあって、その中身をlog(対数)をとり、からのリストにどんどん入れていくということが表現したいのですが、どのように記述したらよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import math

arr = [1., 2., 3.]

# 方法1: 愚直にforループを使う
result = []
for x in arr:
  result.append(math.log(x))

# 方法2: リスト内包表記を使う
result = [math.log(x) for x in arr]

# 方法3: mapする
result = map(math.log, arr)
```