# listの整形と正規表現方法

Tags: python, 正規表現

python3で空のリストを用意して、
さまざまな文字列が要素にあるリストの中身を
空リストに要素を追加したいです。

その時に要素の中身が全角のローマ字と数字、記号を持っていたら
追加せず、スキップする処理をしたいのですが
どのように表現すればよいでしょうか。
お教えお願いいたします。

Comment: FYI: [以前の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/55039/19110)と同じ感じで、愚直にループを回す実装の他に、リスト内包表記や`filter`関数を使った実装もできます :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

全角文字の範囲が明確に指定されていないので、一旦全ての全角文字を弾く実装をしてみました。

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[^\x01-\x7E]')
list_a = []
list_b = ['a', 'b', 'Ａ', '1', '１']

for elm in list_b:
    if not re.match(pattern, elm):
        list_a.append(elm)

print(list_a) # => ['a', 'b', '0']
```